# Target of Assignment Error When Renaming Data Frame Column?

Tags: r

I have the several data frames with the following structure loaded as `verifdata` at 12 hour increments (i.e. `verifdata12`, `verifdata24`, `verifdata36`,and so on).

```
> verifdata12
   staid      lat       lon      start        end StormTotalSnow SnowAmt05Prcntl SnowAmt10Prcntl SnowAmt25Prcntl
1    DLH 46.83998 -92.18234 2020-10-17 2020101812            3.8             1.1             1.3             1.9
2  GRBM5 47.40700 -93.48940 2020-10-17 2020101812            4.5             1.6             1.9             2.7
3  BRAM5 46.34330 -94.20860 2020-10-17 2020101812            1.1             0.0             0.0             0.2
4  CSLM5 47.38470 -94.61470 2020-10-17 2020101812            4.6             1.5             1.7             2.5
5  TOGM5 47.86630 -93.02660 2020-10-17 2020101812            3.0             0.5             0.8             1.7
6  COTM5 47.16870 -92.46290 2020-10-17 2020101812            2.5             0.8             1.0             1.6
7  DLHM5 46.83680 -92.21080 2020-10-17 2020101812            3.6             1.1             1.3             1.8
8  BNDM5 47.97530 -91.45560 2020-10-17 2020101812            2.0             0.4             0.7             1.4
9  EMBM5 47.65810 -92.19580 2020-10-17 2020101812            3.1             1.0             1.2             2.1
10 GMRM5 47.75180 -90.32820 2020-10-17 2020101812            0.3             0.1             0.3             0.6
11 GRPM5 47.24360 -93.49750 2020-10-17 2020101812            3.9             1.3             1.6             2.3
12 GNFM5 48.16030 -90.88420 2020-10-17 2020101812            1.7             0.5             0.8             1.6
13   INL 48.56140 -93.39810 2020-10-17 2020101812            1.2             0.0             0.0             0.1
```

The column names for each data frame are all the same, so I need to change them to their representative hour before merging them together. For example, the 6th column is named `StormTotalSnow` and I want to change it to `StormTotalSnowF12`.

I have the following `for` loop to go change each column name for each data frame, adding the 'F##' at the end of it.

```
f <- c('12', '24', '36', '48', '60')
for(i in f){
  names(eval(as.name(paste('verifdata', i, sep = ''))))[6] <-  paste("StormTotalSnowF", i, sep = '')
  names(eval(as.name(paste('verifdata', i, sep = ''))))[7] <-  paste("SnowAmt05PrcntlF", i, sep = '')...
}
```

However, I keep getting an error.

```
>   names(eval(as.name(paste('verifdata', i, sep = ''))))[6] <-  paste("StormTotalSnowF", i, sep = '')
Error in names(eval(as.name(paste("verifdata", i, sep = ""))))[6] <- paste("StormTotalSnowF",  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

But if I run just the left side of the command line, it's fine and produces the correct column name.

```
> names(eval(as.name(paste('verifdata', i, sep = ''))))[6]
[1] "StormTotalSnow"
```

I also tried just running it with the straight string, thinking the `paste` function was the problem, but to no avail.

```
> names(eval(as.name(paste('verifdata', i, sep = ''))))[6] <- "StormTotalSnowF12"
Error in names(eval(as.name(paste("verifdata", i, sep = ""))))[6] <- "StormTotalSnowF12" : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We load all the dataset objects into a `list`, loop over the `list` and rename the column

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

# // get the object into a list
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = '^verifdata\\d+$'))

# // loop over the list with imap
lst1 <- imap(lst1, ~ {
            # // extract the numeric part from the list name
            nm1 <- readr::parse_number(.y)
            .x %>%
               # // rename the StormTotalSnow, SnowAmt05PrcntlF
               rename_at(vars("StormTotalSnow", "SnowAmt05PrcntlF"),
                       ~ str_c(., nm1))
        })

 
# // it is better to keep it in a list, but if we want
# // to update the objects in global env, use list2env
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or if we want to use the OP's code, use `assign` to change the objects in global env

```
f <- c('12', '24', '36', '48', '60')
for(i in f){
   # // construct the object name
   nm1 <- paste0('verifdata', i)
   # // get the value of object
   tmp <- get(nm1)
   # // find the location of the columns
   i1 <- match(c("StormTotalSnow", "SnowAmt05PrcntlF"), names(tmp))
   # // change the names to new names
   names(tmp)[i1] <- paste0(c("StormTotalSnow", "SnowAmt05PrcntlF"), i)
   # // assign to update the objects in global env
   assign(nm1, tmp)

   }
```